# Integrating a Web Application with BOX.NET using Content API

Tags: box-api

I am in the process of conducting a POC for integrating one of our Corporate Applications with BOX.NET. 
The Corporate application resides over Amazon Cloud and I would like to use that App to perform CRUD operations on BOX.

Can I go ahead and start using the Content API (REST) provided by BOX.NET? On the BOX side I would have to go and register my application to obtain a API KEY. Please confirm if my understanding is correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's correct.  To start using the Box.com API you should go to http://developers.box.com and get an API key for your application.  Depending on the language you like to code in, there are SDKs you can use, or you can code directly against the REST Content API.

The Box APIs are free to build against.  Users that login to your application will have to go through an OAuth2 flow to allow your application to access their Box content.